# load data from a list of lines in PERL

Tags: perl, list

I have a file with a GI list. Each GI is on a separate line. I am trying to call up each line so that I can create another subroutine for the GI on each line. The subroutine will look up the Tax ID for each of the GI and then print them out, separated by a tab.  How would I call up each GI separately so that my subroutine can look it up?
Thank you

Comment: What's GI? What's Tax ID?

Comment: A GI is just a set of numbers referring to a sequence of proteins. I have a list of GI numbers, and I want to be able to call up each set of numbers, put them into a variable and run a sub routine on each set of numbers.

Comment: Please provide a short sample input.

Comment: Sample input, sample code - these things go a long way to eliciting useful answers on stack overflow.

Comment: *A GI is just a set of numbers* --So a single GI is a set of numbers.  Now, what's a 'set of numbers'?

Answer (score 1):

> Each GI is on a separate line...The subroutine will look up the Tax ID for each of the GI and then
>   print them out, separated by a tab.

data.txt:

```
100
200
300
```

...

```
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use 5.016;
use Data::Dumper;

sub get_tax_id {
    my $gi = shift;

    #get tax id somehow(you might want to check out bioperl):
    my $tax_id = substr $gi, 0, 1;

    return $tax_id;
}


my @tax_ids;
my $fname = 'data.txt';

open my $INFILE, '<', $fname
    or die "Couldn't open $fname for reading: $!";

while (my $line = <$INFILE>) {
    chomp $line;
    push @tax_ids, get_tax_id($line);
}

close $INFILE;

{
    local $" = "\t";  
    say "@tax_ids";
}

--output:--
1   2   3
```

`$"` -- When an array is interpolated into a double quoted string, the 
       value of `$"` is used between elements. By default, `$"` is equal to 
       a space.

`local` -- the previous value for the variable is restored when the enclosing scope is exited.  The enclosing scope is marked by the braces.